# Use jQuery or Javascript to move elements into View

Tags: jquery, plugins, jquery-animate

For my website I want to have divs out of the viewport (ie left:3000px;top:1500px;) that the browsers animates to when the user clicks on an anchor link (scrolling disabled). I know there is a plugin out there but can't find any.

Comment: You want the browser view-port to animate **to** the element, or for the element to animate **into** the view-port?

Comment: I want the viewport to animate to the element. I just found it! http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ScrollTo Plugin does the trick - wow I can't believe I couldn't find it earlier. http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/